# Adding Swapcase class to string

Tags: ruby, string, class, methods

Trying to create a method for String class that will return a string swapcased. I have written two different methods

```
class String
  def to_alternating_case
    self.swapcase
  end
end
```

The above code works for all strings entered. However if the following code is entered:

```
class String
  def to_alternating_case
    self.swapcase!
  end
end
```

Then a string which contains all numbers will return nil. Can someone explain why these behave differently when it comes to string containing only numbers?

Comment: If a method has no explicit receiver, the receiver is assumed to be `self`. Therefore, you can replace `self.swapcase` with just `swapcase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are all in the manual.

[`String#swapcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-swapcase-21):

> Equivalent to `String#swapcase`, but modifies the receiver in place, returning `str`, **or `nil` if no changes were made**. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.